# why TimeUnit.convert() dont convert correctly in Java?

Tags: java, time, converters

So I am trying to convert the time from nanoseconds to minutes.
My Code looks like that:

```
long startTime=System.nanoTime();
//some code...
long endTime=System.nanoTime();
long estimatedTime=endTime-startTime;

long estimatedTime2=TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(estimatedTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
System.out.println(estimatedTime2 +","+estimatedTime);
```

**The output**:

```
estimatedTime is always in nanoseconds
estimatedTime2 is always 0;
```

According to the JavaDoc - [TimeUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html):

```
public long convert(long sourceDuration, TimeUnit sourceUnit)
```

The method suppose to return `long` into estimatedTime2.

What is the correct form to use this conversion types ?

Thanks you !

Comment: [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org) along with observed and expected behavior descriptions please.

Comment: the possibility the estimatedTime2 is always 0 could be due to the fact that the calculated  estimatedTime is 0 because not enough time has elapsed in between your startTime and endTime

Comment: print out the estimatedTime before you try to solve for estimatedTime2 and see what you get

Comment: Print estimatedTime as well, see its value. If it's value is too small too be converted to minutes, you will always get zero.

Comment: Why are you printing `estimatedTime2` *twice*?

Answer (score 2):

Unless the difference between endTime and startTime is over a minute, the answer is zero. Note that the convert() return value isn't a float or double (meaning no decimal point)

Comment: Thank you !  So is there an elegant way to convert into minutes a time that is less than 60 seconds ? without using hardcoded numbers to divide.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply do it by hand without all the overhead -

```
float minutesElapsed = estimatedTime / 1000 / 1000 / 1000 / 60;

nano / 1000 -> micro / 1000 -> milli  / 1000 -> sec / 60 -> minutes
```